# End to end Apache Camel Google pubsub example anywhere?

Tags: apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to use the Google Pubsub component in a Camel application. I can't seem to find a basic example of this anywhere. Can someone point me to one or put it here? TIA

Comment: Try look in the unit test of the component

Comment: Where would this be found? I looked at https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/google-pubsub-component.html but didn't see it.

Comment: The Camel source code is here: https://github.com/apache/camel

Comment: Sadly that is not end user code, it just tests parts of the code.